# How to validate an entity that has been expanded using MetadataType?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, entity-framework-4

I have an EF entity Respondent that is automatically generated by EF from the database).

I had to expand this entity to add some validation rules and attributes to use within my View:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(RespondentMetadata))]
public partial class Respondent { }

public class RespondentMetadata
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in my controller, I need to check if this Respondent object has indeed value in FirstName (without checking the value explicitly, because I may have large number of such properties with various validation rules).

This check can be anywhere not necessary in [HttpPost] action (so, ModelState.IsValid N/A here).

How can I validate the entire entity anywhere in code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The 'Text-Book-Way' is to add validation to your Model.

then you can make a check like

```
if (Respondent.IsValid())
{
}
```

Comment: I can add that you can achieve this in various ways for example create common interface for your classes like ICanBeValidated and write IsValid extension method with for this interface.

Comment: interesting. whats advantage unless you want to abstract it further into a common method?

Comment: Thanks a lot, true, this seems to be a solid approach. I was just thinking that EF has some built-in mechanism, something like the previous answer..

Comment: @DaveA as you said the only advantage is to abstract validation logic into a common method. One method is more maintainable that N.. unless that N methods are codegenerated.

Comment: True. We could spin this thread into all kinds of place, but point acknowledged.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`Validator.ValidateObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411788.aspx) method in order to perform validation anywhere in the code, but for that you need to stop using the `MetadataTypeAttribute` and explicitly associate the metadata class using the [`TypeDescriptor.AddProviderTransparent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783170.aspx) method.

Sample:

```
var respondent = new Respondent();

var provider = new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(
    typeof (Respondent), 
    typeof (RespondentMetadata));

TypeDescriptor.AddProviderTransparent(provider, typeof (Respondent));

Validator.ValidateObject(
    respondent, 
    new ValidationContext(respondent, null, null));
```

The `Validator` class does not seem to honor the attribute so this is the only workaround that I'm aware.

Comment: i like the implementation.

Comment: Oh, mama! :) AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider :P That's probably the longest thing I have ever seen lol. Thanks a lot! I will give it a try.